# Range of cell value based on another range value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate column C values on my sheet based on a value in column A. So if column A value is 1, then i want the value in corresponding cell in column C to be 10, else do nothing.

```
Sub test()

For Each cell In Sheets("Report").Range("A9:A" & LastRow)
   If cell.Value = 1 Then
      cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 10
   End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help and show me a better way if there is.
thanks

Comment: What problem you are facing? You do not define `LastRow`. Also define `cell` as `Range`.

Comment: I'm getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below sub.

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In sh.Range("A9:A" & LastRow)
       If cel.Value = 1 Then
          cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = 10
       End If
    Next cel
    Set sh = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Although may i ask why you used this "Set sh = Nothing"?

Comment: `Set sh = Nothing` line clear the memory.